# Change property value without destroying binding to support two-way binding

Tags: qt, data-binding, qml, 2-way-object-databinding

I want to create a custom component, which allows two-way binding with the following (traditional) setup:

```
// main.qml
property var someStoredValue: someInitialValue // may be C++ property in real application
MyCustomComponent
{
    myProperty: someStoredValue // this binding will be destroyed on user input
    onMyPropertyChanged: someStoredValue = myProperty
}

// MyCustomComponent.qml
Item
{
    property var myProperty: null
    MouseArea
    {
        anchors.fill: parent
        onClicked: myProperty = "some text or other value" // breaks the binding set in main.qml
    }
}
```

`MyCustomComponent` should be able to update `myProperty` (programmatically), without destroying the binding between `someStoredValue` and `myProperty`. How can I change the implementation of `MyCustomComponent` to achieve my goal?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One solution would be to use [`QObject::setProperty`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qobject.html#setProperty) to update the `myProperty` without breaking the binding.

First, we should expose the `QObject::setProperty` to QML, f.ex. using a singleton object:

```
#include <QObject>

class QmlHelper : public QObject
{
  Q_OBJECT
public:
  Q_INVOKABLE void setValue (QObject *pObject, const QString& name, QVariant v)
  {
    QByteArray n = name.toUtf8();
    if (v.isNull())
      v = QVariant(pObject->property(n.data()).userType(), nullptr); // ensure v is of correct type
    pObject->setProperty(n.data(), v);
  }
};
```

You should register the singleton type:

```
qmlRegisterSingletonType<QmlHelper>("MyUri", 1, 0, "QmlHelper", [](QQmlEngine *, QJSEngine *) -> QObject* {return new QmlHelper();});
```

`MyCustomComponent` could now be implemented as:

```
Item
{
    id: myComponent
    property var myProperty: null
    MouseArea
    {
        anchors.fill: parent
        onClicked: QmlHelper.setValue(myComponent, "myProperty", "some text or other value"); // updates myProperty without breaking the binding
    }
}
```

**DISCLAIMER**: Changing QML properties from C++ is a rather tricky solution and not well documented. Use at your own risk.

Answer (score 2):

One solution would be to use a `Binding` object to update `myProperty` inside `MyCustomComponent`, instead of directly changing the value:

```
// MyCustomComponent.qml
Item
{
    property var myProperty: null
    Binding on myProperty
    {
        id: myPropertyUpdater
        function set(newValue) {value = newValue; when = true; when = false;}
        when: false
    }

    MouseArea
    {
        anchors.fill: parent
        onClicked: myPropertyUpdater.set("some text or other value")
    }
}
```

The trick is to shortly set the `when` property of `Binding` to true, to propagate the new value. After inactivating the `Binding` (`when = false;`), any previous direct binding will be restored, as stated in the [docs](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qml-qtqml-binding.html#when-prop):

> When the binding becomes inactive again, any direct bindings that were
> previously set on the property will be restored.

Disadvantage is that if the changed value isn't stored in the `onMyPropertyChanged` handler, `myProperty` will be restored to the old value.