# How to preserve bindings in a re-usable QML component?

Tags: qt, binding, qml, slider

I'm trying to preserve the double binding logic from within my slider component such that it behaves the same as the builtin `Slider`:

```
import QtQuick 2.0
import QtQuick.Window 2.0
import QtQuick.Controls 2.15
import QtQuick.Layouts 1.15

Window {
    ColumnLayout {
        SimpleSlider { id: sslider0; value: .3 }
        SimpleSlider { id: sslider1; value: 1 - sslider0.value }
        Slider { id: slider0; value: .3 }
        Slider { id: slider1; value: 1 - slider0.value }
    }
}
```

Unfortunately, it doesn't:

[image: slider]

Here is my `SimpleSlider.qml`:

```
import QtQuick 2.4

Item {
    id: simple_slider
    property real value: .5
    property real min_value: 0
    property real max_value: 1

    width: childrenRect.width
    height: childrenRect.height

    function linear(a, b, x) { return (x - a) / (b - a) }
    function mix(a, b, x)    { return a * (1 - x) + b * x }

    FontMetrics { id: fontMetrics }

    Rectangle {
        id: main_box
        width: Math.max(txt_label.width + 10, 50)
        height: fontMetrics.height + 10
        radius: 2
        color: "darkgrey"
    }

    Rectangle {
        id: filled_box
        width: linear(min_value, max_value, value) * main_box.width
        height: main_box.height
        radius: main_box.radius
        color: "orange"
    }

    Text {
        id: txt_label
        text: value.toFixed(3)
        anchors.centerIn: main_box
    }

    MouseArea {
        property real xval: simple_slider.value

        id: drag_slider
        anchors.fill: parent
        onPositionChanged: xval = get_value_from_pos(mouse.x)
        function get_value_from_pos(x) {
            var v = Math.min(Math.max(linear(0, main_box.width, x), 0), 1)
            return mix(min_value, max_value, v)
        }
    }

    Binding {
        target: simple_slider
        property: "value"
        value: drag_slider.xval
    }
}
```

The reason is obvious: I'm overwriting the binding here: `onPositionChanged: xval = get_value_from_pos(mouse.x)` (and confirmed by `QT_LOGGING_RULES="qt.qml.binding.removal.info=true"`)

But while I identified the core of the issue, I'm not sure how to deal with it.

There might be a twisted design where I would turn this into a declarative based form using the position change state, but then I'll have a similar issue when my slider will also accept the value from a `TextInput` (which will need to update the value in a similar fashion in its `onAccepted` callback).

Comment: Two way bindings are always hard to get right in qml. If you want it to work like the built in Slider, you might want to take a look at the source code to see how Qt handles it. Or you could just change your SimpleSlider to derive from a standard Slider.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Change property value without destroying binding to support two-way binding](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53970150/change-property-value-without-destroying-binding-to-support-two-way-binding)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

JarMan's hint is a good one. I tried to solve the bidirectional binding problem in your example, but had no luck. So I present to you the styled standard slider:
[image]
This is my `SimpleSlider.qml`:

```
import QtQuick 2.15
import QtQuick.Templates 2.15 as T

T.Slider {
    id: slider

    width: 200
    height: 40

    background: Rectangle {
        color: "darkgrey"

        Rectangle {
            width: slider.visualPosition * parent.width
            height: parent.height
            color: "orange"
        }
    }

    Text {
        text: slider.value.toFixed(3)
        anchors.centerIn: slider
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Edited SimpleSlider.qml:

```
import QtQuick 2.15
import QtQml 2.15

Item {
    id: simple_slider
    property real value: .5
    property real tempValue: value
    property real min_value: 0
    property real max_value: 1
    width: childrenRect.width
    height: childrenRect.height

    function linear(a, b, x) { return (x - a) / (b - a) }
    function mix(a, b, x)    { return a * (1 - x) + b * x }

    FontMetrics { id: fontMetrics }

    Rectangle {
        id: main_box
        width: Math.max(txt_label.width + 10, 50)
        height: fontMetrics.height + 10
        radius: 2
        color: "darkgrey"
    }

    Rectangle {
        id: filled_box
        width: linear(min_value, max_value, tempValue) * main_box.width
        height: main_box.height
        radius: main_box.radius
        color: "orange"
    }

    Text {
        id: txt_label
        text: tempValue.toFixed(3)
        anchors.centerIn: main_box
    }

    MouseArea {
        ///property real xval: simple_slider.value

        id: drag_slider
        anchors.fill: parent
        onPositionChanged: tempValue = get_value_from_pos(mouse.x)
        onReleased: tempValue = Qt.binding(function() { return value })

        function get_value_from_pos(x) {
            var v = Math.min(Math.max(linear(0, main_box.width, x), 0), 1)
            return mix(min_value, max_value, v)
        }
    }

    Binding on value {
        when: drag_slider.pressed
        value: tempValue
        restoreMode: Binding.RestoreBinding

    }
}
```